# XGBoost predict_proba slow inference performance

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I trained 2 gradient-boosting models on the same data, using Scikit-learn and XGBoost.

Scikit-learn model

```py
GradientBoostingClassifier(
    n_estimators=5,
    learning_rate=0.17,
    max_depth=5,
    verbose=2
)
```

XGBoost model

```py
XGBClassifier(
    n_estimators=5,
    learning_rate=0.17,
    max_depth=5,
    verbosity=2,
    eval_metric="logloss"
)
```

Then I checked inference performance:

- Xgboost: 9.7 ms ± 84.6 µs per loop
- Scikit-learn: 426 µs ± 12.5 µs per loop

Why XGBoost is so slow?

Comment: @jared_mamrot yes, it's a wrapper. But how xgb.train is related to inference speed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Why is xgboost so slow?": `XGBClassifier()` is the scikit-learn API for XGBoost (see e.g. https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBClassifier for more details). If you call the function directly (not through an API) it will be faster. To compare the performance of the two functions it makes sense to call each function directly, instead of calling one function directly and one function through an API. Here is an example:

```py
# benchmark_xgboost_vs_sklearn.py
# Adapted from `xgboost_test.py` by Jacob Schreiber 
# (https://gist.github.com/jmschrei/6b447aada61d631544cd)

"""
Benchmarking scripts for XGBoost versus sklearn (time and accuracy)
"""

import time
import random
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier

random.seed(0)
np.random.seed(0)

def make_dataset(n=500, d=10, c=2, z=2):
    """
    Make a dataset of size n, with d dimensions and m classes,
    with a distance of z in each dimension, making each feature equally
    informative.
    """

    # Generate our data and our labels
    X = np.concatenate([np.random.randn(n, d) + z*i for i in range(c)])
    y = np.concatenate([np.ones(n) * i for i in range(c)])

    # Generate a random indexing
    idx = np.arange(n*c)
    np.random.shuffle(idx)

    # Randomize the dataset, preserving data-label pairing
    X = X[idx]
    y = y[idx]

    # Return x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test
    return X[::2], X[1::2], y[::2], y[1::2]

def main():
    """
    Run SKLearn, and then run xgboost,
    then xgboost via SKLearn XGBClassifier API wrapper
    """

    # Generate the dataset
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = make_dataset(10, z=100)
    n_estimators=5
    max_depth=5
    learning_rate=0.17

    # sklearn first
    tic = time.time()
    clf = GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=n_estimators,
        max_depth=max_depth, learning_rate=learning_rate)
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print("SKLearn GBClassifier: {}s".format(time.time() - tic))
    print("Acc: {}".format(clf.score(X_test, y_test)))
    print(y_test.sum())
    print(clf.predict(X_test))

    # Convert the data to DMatrix for xgboost
    dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, label=y_train)
    dtest  = xgb.DMatrix(X_test, label=y_test)
    # Loop through multiple thread numbers for xgboost
    for threads in 1, 2, 4:
        # xgboost's sklearn interface
        tic = time.time()
        clf = xgb.XGBModel(n_estimators=n_estimators, max_depth=max_depth,
            learning_rate=learning_rate, nthread=threads)
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
        print("SKLearn XGBoost API Time: {}s".format(time.time() - tic))
        preds = np.round( clf.predict(X_test) )
        acc = 1. - (np.abs(preds - y_test).sum()  / y_test.shape[0])
        print("Acc: {}".format( acc ))
        print("{} threads: ".format( threads ))
        tic = time.time()
        param = {
                  'max_depth' : max_depth,
                        'eta' : 0.1,
                      'silent': 1,
                   'objective':'binary:logistic',
                     'nthread': threads
                }
        bst = xgb.train( param, dtrain, n_estimators,
            [(dtest, 'eval'), (dtrain, 'train')] )
        print("XGBoost (no wrapper) Time: {}s".format(time.time() - tic))
        preds = np.round(bst.predict(dtest) )
        acc = 1. - (np.abs(preds - y_test).sum() / y_test.shape[0])
        print("Acc: {}".format(acc))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Summarised results:**

sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier()

- Time: 0.003237009048461914s
- Accuracy: 1.0

sklearn xgboost API wrapper XGBClassifier()

- Time: 0.3436141014099121s
- Accuracy: 1.0

XGBoost (no wrapper) xgb.train()

- Time: 0.0028612613677978516s
- Accuracy: 1.0

Answer (score 0):

You can try using XGBoost with Intel optimizations to improve the performance on Intel hardwares.
Intel-optimized XGBoost can be installed in the following ways:

1. As a part of Intel® AI Analytics Toolkit (https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/ai-analytics-toolkit-download.html)
2. From PyPI repository, using pip package manager: pip install xgboost
3. From Anaconda package manager:
   Using Intel channel: conda install xgboost –c intel

   Using conda-forge channel: conda install xgboost –c conda-forge
4. As a Docker container (provided you have a DockerHub account) (https://hub.docker.com/r/intel/intel-optimized-ml/tags?page=1&name=xgboost)

Please check out the link, https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/easy-introduction-xgboost-for-intel-architecture.html to get started with Intel Optimization for XGBoost.

Comment: I am afraid this does not provide an answer to the question, which is *why* XGBoost is so slow in the specific conditions used, and not how it can get faster in general.