# XGBoost: How to use a DMatrix with scikit-learn interface .fit

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, xgboost

I am currently using the scikit-learn interface for XGBoost in my project. However, I have an extremely large dataset, and each time I call `.fit`, the data is converted to a DMatrix, which is very time-consuming, especially when using a GPU that trains relatively fast. I've benchmarked using the native interface by using a single DMatrix for each fit, and the results show a significant difference (14s per fit vs 0.9s per fit). The problem is, I need a scikit-learn model so that it works with the rest of my program.

Is there a way to use a DMatrix with the scikit-learn interface in XGBoost, or any workarounds to avoid the repeated conversion to DMatrix while still maintaining compatibility with scikit-learn?

See the below code to get a reproducible way to cause this issue.

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
import xgboost as xgb

# Large synthetic dataset
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=500_0000, n_features=20,
                           n_informative=10, n_redundant=10, random_state=42)

# scikit-learn
t = time.time()
model = XGBClassifier(tree_method="gpu_hist", gpu_id=0,
                      predictor="gpu_predictor", max_bin=256)
model.fit(X, y)
print("scikit-learn interface: ", time.time() - t)

# scikit-learn again
t = time.time()
model.fit(X, y)
print("scikit-learn (2nd) interface: ", time.time() - t)

print()

# DMatrix
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(data=X, label=y)
t = time.time()
model = xgb.train({"tree_method": "gpu_hist", "gpu_id": 0,
                  "predictor": "gpu_predictor"}, dtrain)
print("native interface: ", time.time() - t)

# DMatrix again
t = time.time()
model = xgb.train({"tree_method": "gpu_hist", "gpu_id": 0,
                  "predictor": "gpu_predictor"}, dtrain)
print("native (2nd) interface:: ", time.time() - t)
```

Output:

```
scikit-learn interface:  14.393212795257568
scikit-learn (2nd) interface:  14.048950433731079

native interface:  3.9494242668151855
native (2nd) interface::  0.9888997077941895
```

As you can see, there is a big time discrepancy between scikit-learn and native.

Comment: Is the scikit-learn `ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier()` what you're looking for? E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66216716/12957340

Comment: No. XGBoost is essential for what I'm doing as the datasets get really large, and unfortunately the scikit-learn interface does not support GPUs or distributed training with Dask, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Quick note on XGBoost with 'hist' tree_method: it swaps DMatrix for QuantileDMatrix internally to save memory. Just be cautious – if your input data (like a NumPy array) is on the CPU while training uses CUDA, there's a performance hit. Data first hits the CPU, then heads to the GPU.

What you can do:

1. Transform the X,y before feeding to XGBClassifier to Cuda Dataframe
   see [cudf](https://pypi.org/project/cudf-cu12/).
2. Transform the X,y before feeding to XGBClassifier to
   Cupy numpy, see [cupy](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/install.html).
3. Overwrite the _create_dmatrix function of
   the XGBModel Class as follows, see comparisons below.

```html
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=500_0000, n_features=20,
                           n_informative=10, n_redundant=10, random_state=42)

# scikit-learn
t = time.time()
model = XGBClassifier(tree_method="gpu_hist", gpu_id=0,
                      predictor="gpu_predictor", max_bin=256)
model.fit(X, y)
print("scikit-learn interface: ", time.time() - t)

# scikit-learn again
t = time.time()
model.fit(X, y)
print("scikit-learn (2nd) interface: ", time.time() - t)

print()

#CUPY
t = time.time()
model = XGBClassifier(tree_method="gpu_hist", gpu_id=0,
                      predictor="gpu_predictor", max_bin=256)

model.fit(cp.array(X), cp.array(y))
print("CUPY-scikit-learn interface: ", time.time() - t)

t = time.time()
model.fit(cp.array(X), cp.array(y))
print("CUPY-scikit-learn (2nd) interface: ", time.time() - t)

print()

#CUDF
t = time.time()
model = XGBClassifier(tree_method="gpu_hist", gpu_id=0,
                      predictor="gpu_predictor", max_bin=256)
model.fit(cudf.DataFrame(X), cudf.DataFrame(y))
print("CUDF-scikit-learn interface: ", time.time() - t)

t = time.time()
model.fit(cudf.DataFrame(X), cudf.DataFrame(y))
print("CUDF-scikit-learn (2nd) interface: ", time.time() - t)

print()

#OVERWRITE _create_dmatrix
class MyXGB(XGBClassifier):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):  # pylint: disable=useless-parent-delegation
        """Initalize Trainer."""
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def _create_dmatrix(self, ref: Optional[DMatrix], **kwargs: Any) -> DMatrix:
        return DMatrix(**kwargs, nthread=self.n_jobs)

t = time.time()
model = MyXGB(tree_method="gpu_hist", gpu_id=0,
                      predictor="gpu_predictor", max_bin=256)
model.fit(X, y)
print("OVERWRITE-scikit-learn interface: ", time.time() - t)

t = time.time()
model.fit(cp.array(X), cp.array(y))
print("OVERWRITE-scikit-learn (2nd) interface: ", time.time() - t)

print()

# DMatrix
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(data=X, label=y)
t = time.time()
model = xgb.train({"tree_method": "gpu_hist", "gpu_id": 0,
                  "predictor": "gpu_predictor"}, dtrain)
print("native interface: ", time.time() - t)

# DMatrix again
t = time.time()
model = xgb.train({"tree_method": "gpu_hist", "gpu_id": 0,
                  "predictor": "gpu_predictor"}, dtrain)
print("native (2nd) interface:: ", time.time() - t)
```

OUTPUT:

```html
scikit-learn interface:  21.925138473510742
scikit-learn (2nd) interface:  20.68904447555542

CUPY-scikit-learn interface:  5.335642099380493
CUPY-scikit-learn (2nd) interface:  5.236214876174927

CUDF-scikit-learn interface:  5.496228933334351
CUDF-scikit-learn (2nd) interface:  5.3957905769348145

OVERWRITE-scikit-learn interface:  7.505085468292236
OVERWRITE-scikit-learn (2nd) interface:  5.462920427322388

native interface:  1.2605454921722412
native (2nd) interface::  0.5620841979980469
```

Not perfect but better.

Comment: Plus, timing the xgb.Dmatrix creation would result in almost the same time between natives and adjusted scikit-learn methods.

Answer (score 0):

The `xgboost.DMatrix` class is an XGBoost-specific data container class, and it is generally not supported  by the Scikit-Learn framework as a valid argument in `fit(X, y)` and `predict(X)` method calls. Talking about `XGBClassifier` and `XGBRegressor` model classes in particular, then they expect that the incoming data containers are fully Scikit-Learn compatible (meaning Numpy arrays, and Pandas data frames); they will perform the "conversion" into `xgboost.DMatrix` data container class automatically.

The workaround to your problem would be to create your own Scikit-Learn style model class(es), which would accept/expect `xgboost.DMatrix` arguments, and if present, passed them on directly to the underlying XGBoost Learner API methods as-is, without performing any extra conversions on them. Please note that your `fit(X, y)` method implementation must disregard the `y` argument (because this information is already contained in the `X` argument).

Something like this:

```py
class MyXGBTrainer(BaseEstimatir):

  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def fit(self, X, y):
    if not isinstance(X, DMatrix):
      raise TypeError()
    self.model_ = xgb.train(data = X)

  def predict(self, X):
    if not isinstance(X, DMatrix):
      raise TypeError()
    return self.model_.predict(data = X)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the data normally distributed? If not, normalize it, then take a random sample.

```
df = df.sample(frac=0.50)
```